# Logging out from an iframe not clearing cookies in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, php, cookies

The setup is as follows.

A login form from my site (site A) is embedded as an iframe in another site (site B). When a user logs in, a cookie is set like this:

```
setcookie("cookieFromSiteA", $r_string, time() + 3600, "/;domain=".$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"].";SameSite=None; Secure");
```

where `$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]` is `.siteA.com`, and `$rstring` is the cookie's value. Site A's content is always kept within the iframe.

Once the user tries to log out from site A, the cookies are cleared (with [jQuery cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie)¹), and everything works as expected - in Firefox. Google Chrome keeps the user logged in. Other browsers are of no interest at the moment.

This only happens if site A is embedded as an iframe inside site B. If the user accesses site A directly, and tries logging in and out, everything works fine, regardless of the browser.

I only have control of the code on site A.

---

¹ I've also tried clearing it with regular methods, such as:

`document.cookie = "cookieFromSiteA=;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT;path=/;domain=.sitea.com;SameSite=None;Secure"`,

or with `Max-Age=0` instead of `expires=...`, and with PHP's

`setcookie("cookieFromSiteA",$rstring, -1,"/;domain=".$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"].";SameSite=None; Secure")`

Comment: _“A login form from my site (site A) is embedded as an iframe in another site (site B)”_ - and to login, users need to do what - enter their credentials, directly inside that iframe? That would be rather dangerous to begin with. With this embedded via an iframe, users have no quick and easy way to verify (like they would have via the address bar, with a “normal” login page) they are actually entering their data into _your_ form, and not a copy set up by a phisher.

Comment: Instead of just trying to clear the cookies via jQuery, have you tried doing that from the server side? You are probably fighting some sort of privacy setting here, regarding use of 3rd-party cookies; whether you attempt to delete them the way they were set (presumbably via HTTP), or client-side only, _might_ make a difference.

Comment: @CBroe Yes, in order to be able to log in, users need to enter their credentials. The login is for a webapp which a beauty salon is using, and that same webapp has a login page for the clients. However, the salon wanted to integrate that login with their WordPress website, and the iframe is the easiest solution. As for the cookie clearing, yes, a server-side clearing is also in place, but it seems to make no difference here.